# Indy SMTP server is refusing connection

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy10

I am at the very beginning of a new project, in an area which is new to me.

I want to code an application which which will act as a middle-man Windows based email clients, such as Thunderbird, etc, and a remote SMTP server. The reason being that my application will perform some slight manipulation of emails as they pass through.

So, I figured that I will want a `TIdSMTPServer`. I decided to use port 6789, in case of any possible conflict (which I doubt, but ... j.i.c).

I set the SMTP server's `DefaultPort` to 6789, and I also bound the SMTP server to `127.0.0.1:6789` in the `Bindings` property (and, as @SirRufo pointed out, I set the server.active to true)..

Now, I added a button with some test code, based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341944/indy-and-smtps-cannot-connect). The only change I made was to change the port from `SMTP.Port := 465;` to `SMTP.Port := IdSMTPServer.DefaultPort`  (host is left as `127.0.0.1`).

However, when I attempt to connect my `IdSMTPServer`'s `IdSMTPServerConnect()` method is never called and I get an exception, "EIdSocketError # 10061 Connection refused".

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

(and is there any guide or tutorial describing the use of IdSMTPServer?)

Comment: Did you activate the server? `IdSMTPServer1.Active := True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem to connect to the `TIdSMTPServer`

```
type
  TForm1 = class( TForm )
    IdSMTP1 : TIdSMTP;
    IdSMTPServer1 : TIdSMTPServer;
    Button1 : TButton;
    ListBox1 : TListBox;
    procedure Button1Click( Sender : TObject );
    procedure IdSMTPServer1Connect( AContext : TIdContext );
    procedure IdSMTPServer1Disconnect( AContext : TIdContext );
  private
    procedure Log( const AMsg : string );
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1 : TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click( Sender : TObject );
begin
  // Server Settings
  IdSMTPServer1.DefaultPort := 6728;
  IdSMTPServer1.OnConnect := IdSMTPServer1Connect;
  IdSMTPServer1.OnDisconnect := IdSMTPServer1Disconnect;
  // Client Settings
  IdSMTP1.Host := '127.0.0.1';
  IdSMTP1.Port := IdSMTPServer1.DefaultPort;
  // Connect Client to Server
  IdSMTPServer1.Active := True;
  try
    IdSMTP1.Connect;
    IdSMTP1.Disconnect( True );
  finally
    IdSMTPServer1.Active := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Log( const AMsg : string );
begin
  if MainThreadID = TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID
  then
  begin
    ListBox1.ItemIndex := ListBox1.Items.Add( AMsg );
  end
  else
    TThread.Queue( nil,
        procedure
      begin
        Log( AMsg )
      end );
end;

procedure TForm1.IdSMTPServer1Connect( AContext : TIdContext );
begin
  Log( 'Connect' );
end;

procedure TForm1.IdSMTPServer1Disconnect( AContext : TIdContext );
begin
  Log( 'Disconnect' );
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a 1,000,000. Your code looked great, so I went through mine line by line & saw that I had coded `      TestIdSMTP.Host:='127.0.1.1'; // IP Address of SMTP server`  read it carefully, especially the 3rd part Grrrr. Thanks for making me slow down & examine it!